# Qmake doesn't generate a header file

Tags: qmake

So here is my problem. I just started studying Qt. I study from a book about Qt. There is shown how to make a simple dialog. The dialog is made with Qt Designer. The book says that when I'm done making the design in the file called gotocelldialog.ui, I need to go to main.cpp and type this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Ui::GoToCellDialog ui;
    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
    ui.setupUi(dialog);
    dialog->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

It is said that when I run this witk Qmake, a header file will be generated from my gotocelldialog.ui. But the only thing that is generated is .pro file. This is its content:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS  +=

FORMS    += \
    gotocelldialog.ui
```

I can't understand why ui_gotocelldialog.h is not generated. I'm using Qt 5.1.1 - the latest version.
Can you explain me this with details because as I said I'm new to Qt and I don't know well how Qmake works. Thanks for reading.

Comment: You need Qt Designer to create gotocelldialog.ui. Check the following link
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

Comment: I did that which is shown in the site you offered but I still can't generate header file. I use QtDesigner and I do everything as it is said but something is not working

Comment: What is your operating system? I'm using Mac and I didn't get any problem.

Comment: I think you're referring to this book "C++ GUI Programming
with Qt 4" by Jasmin Blanchette and Mark Summerfield.

Comment: I think I see where is your problem. You are saying that after running qmake, it does generate only .pro. Ok, did you run qmake again to generate Makefile and then make to generate the header file.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, open the terminal and go to the folder where your files in, then type the following

This line will generate the .pro file

> > qmake -project

This line will generate the Makefile

> > qmake

This line will generate the rest of files (in your case Forms.app, main.o, and ui_gotocelldialog.h)

> > make

You need gotocelldialog.ui and main.cpp in the same folder (Note: you must have only one .pro file which will be generated by "qmake -project" otherwise you need to specify the .pro file). That being said, if the problem still exists then the problem has nothing to do with qmake or Qt designer.