# QDialog doesn't compile

Tags: qt, qmake

I am facing exactly the same problem as this person:
[Qmake doesn't generate a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316294/qmake-doesnt-generate-a-header-file)
..except that the answers that have been stated doesn't solve my problem. When I 'qmake' my project after 'qmake -project', It doesn't generate the header file as was stated in the book. When I 'make' project following the above two commands, It generates a header file 'ui_gotocell.h' (which corresponds to the name of my project directory, instead of 'ui_gotocelldialog.h' that was used in main.cpp) and terminates the compilation with following error:

```
g++ -c -m32 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../Canopy32/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86/mkspecs/linux-g++-32 -I. -I../Canopy32/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86/include/QtCore -I../Canopy32/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86/include/QtGui -I../Canopy32/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86/include -I. -I. -I. -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:10:2: error: ‘GotoCellDialog’ is not a member of ‘Ui’
  Ui::GotoCellDialog ui;
  ^
main.cpp:10:21: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ui’
  Ui::GotoCellDialog ui;
                    ^
main.cpp:12:2: error: ‘ui’ was not declared in this scope
  ui.setupUi(dialog);
  ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
itqan@Itqan:~/gotocell$
```

I am using Qt 5.4 with GNU GCC compiler on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Does `gotocelldialog.ui` file exist? Do you have `FORMS += gotocelldialog.ui` in your `.pro`?

Comment: Yup, I do have that. Here's a screenshot of my directory: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=85171 and here is the code of header file generated by 'make': http://www.pasteall.org/57208/cpp-qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Ui::GotoCellDialog ui;` to `Ui:Dialog ui;` in `main.cpp`.